# Show weekly posts statistic in WordPress

Tags: count

I create a table in the footer.

I would like to show some statistics, like total posts, weekly posts, total posts of the specific category.

I just echo total posts with `wp_count_posts()->publish;`

What can I do for the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the total post, so in order to get the total post within the last week, it's better if you do this on your `functions.php` file:

```
function get_posts_count_from_last_week($post_type ='post') {
    global $wpdb;

    $numposts = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT COUNT(ID) ".
            "FROM {$wpdb->posts} ".
            "WHERE ".
                "post_status='publish' ".
                "AND post_type= %s ".
                "AND post_date> %s",
            $post_type, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-168 hours'))
        )
    );
    return $numposts;
}
```

And then use it in the footer.

```
<?php echo get_posts_count_from_last_week(); ?>
```

To work with categories we could use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$args = array(
  'cat' => 4,
  'post_type' => 'videos'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $the_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: I use your code. it shows $numposts correct but I get lots of log in debug file

`PHP Notice: The wpdb function was <strong> incorrectly </strong> called. wpdb must establish a database connection for use with escaping.`

second question, is it nessecery to use  $wpdb->close(); before return?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress query supports [Date Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).
To get the specific category, you will need to add category parameter as well.